# Find $\iint_Ty^2dxdy$, where T is the triangle with vertices at (0,0),(2,2) and (3,0)

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a feeling I am meant to split the integrals, but I am struggling to work out which limits to set for my integrals.

I think it should be something like:

$\int_0^x\int_0^2y^2dxdy + \int_0^?\int_2^3y^2dxdy$

I'm not sure what the "?" is meant to be, so if anyone could show me:

1. Whether I am on the right track?
2. How they have actually worked that "?" out?
3. And finally, what to do no next, and how they've gotten their answer.

I'd be awfully greatful!

Comment: Start this problem by drawing the region. Then find the equation of the straight line between $(2,2)$ and $(3,0)$. That equation gives you the upper limit "?" you are looking for

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused by your second comment.
I think I understand what you're saying but I'm confused as to how to work it out.
So would I be solving something like this:
$\int_0^2\int_0^xy^2dydx + \int_2^3\int_y^\frac{6-y}{2}dxdy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O = (0,0), A = (2,2), B = (3,0)$. The equation of the line that passes through $O,A$ is:

$y = x$, and the equation of the line that goes through $A, B$ is: $y = -2x+6$. Thus:

$I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^2 \int_{y}^{\frac{6-y}{2}} y^2dxdy$

Comment: So does this mean we can find the area without splitting the integral?

Comment: Split is not necessary.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry about all the questions. Just want clarification on something. The second integral sets the upper limit (which i assume is the x axis) at 2. I was just wandering what about the distance between 2 and 3 in the triangle? Hope my question makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the $x$ goes from y to $\dfrac{6-y}{2}$, and it does not use $2$ or $3$.